# Searching multiple nested fields not working (ES + ROR)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch

I am trying to do some aggregations which I will use as filters but I am having a problem with searching the fields I am aggregating. This is my mapping:

```
 settings :index => { :number_of_shards => 1 } do
    mapping do
      indexes :id, index: :not_analyzed
      indexes :name
      indexes :summary
      indexes :description


      indexes :occasions, type: 'nested' do
        indexes :id, type: 'integer'
        indexes :occasion_name, type: 'string', index: :not_analyzed
      end

      indexes :courses, type: 'nested' do
        indexes :id, type: 'integer'
        indexes :course_name, type: 'string', index: :not_analyzed
      end
      #
      indexes :allergens, type: 'nested' do
        indexes :id, type: 'integer'
        indexes :allergen_name, type: 'string', index: :not_analyzed
      end
      #
      indexes :cookingtechniques, type: 'nested' do
        indexes :id, type: 'integer'
        indexes :name, type: 'string', index: :not_analyzed
      end

      indexes :cuisine, type: 'nested' do
        indexes :id, type: 'integer'
        indexes :cuisine_name, type: 'string', index: :not_analyzed
      end

    end
  end
```

And this is where I define the query:

```
 def multi_match_query(query)
      {

        bool: {

            should: [
                {
                    nested:{
                        path: 'occasions',
                        query: {
                            multi_match:
                            {
                                      query: query,
                                      type: "best_fields",
                                      fields: ["occasions.occasion_name"]

                                  }
                        }
                    }
                },

                {
                    nested:{
                        path:'courses',
                        query: {
                            multi_match:
                                {
                                    query: query,
                                    type: "best_fields",
                                    fields: ["course_name"]

                                }
                        }
                    }
                },

                {
                    multi_match: {
                        query: query,
                        fields:["name^9", "summary^8", "cuisine_name^7", "description^6"],

                    }
                }
            ]
        }


      }
    end
```

So far I am able to correctly display my aggregations and search on all fields except on "course_name". The other aggregated field is searchable (occasion_name). I want to add the other nested fields in the query as well, and I tried adding them but again, the only nested field that is searchable is occasion_name, all of the other nested fields are not. I checked a couple ES reference books I have but there is nothing like the query I am trying to do which makes me think I can't have more than one nested fields in the query ?

EDIT: Here is my mapping json:

```
{  
   "recipes":{  
      "mappings":{  
         "recipe":{  
            "properties":{  
               "allergens":{  
                  "type":"nested",
                  "properties":{  
                     "allergen_name":{  
                        "type":"string",
                        "index":"not_analyzed"
                     },
                     "id":{  
                        "type":"integer"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "cookingtechniques":{  
                  "type":"nested",
                  "properties":{  
                     "id":{  
                        "type":"integer"
                     },
                     "name":{  
                        "type":"string",
                        "index":"not_analyzed"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "courses":{  
                  "type":"nested",
                  "properties":{  
                     "course_name":{  
                        "type":"string",
                        "index":"not_analyzed"
                     },
                     "id":{  
                        "type":"integer"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "cuisine":{  
                  "type":"nested",
                  "properties":{  
                     "cuisine_name":{  
                        "type":"string",
                        "index":"not_analyzed"
                     },
                     "id":{  
                        "type":"integer"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "description":{  
                  "type":"string"
               },
               "id":{  
                  "type":"string",
                  "index":"not_analyzed"
               },
               "name":{  
                  "type":"string"
               },
               "occasions":{  
                  "type":"nested",
                  "properties":{  
                     "id":{  
                        "type":"integer"
                     },
                     "occasion_name":{  
                        "type":"string",
                        "index":"not_analyzed"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "summary":{  
                  "type":"string"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The query from the search request from RoR:

```
{:query=>
        {:bool=>
          {:should=>
            [{:nested=>{:path=>"occasions", :query=>{:multi_match=>{:query=>"salad", :type=>"best_fields", :fields=>["occasions.occasion_name"]}}}},
             {:nested=>{:path=>"courses", :query=>{:multi_match=>{:query=>"salad", :type=>"best_fields", :fields=>["courses.course_name"]}}}},
             {:multi_match=>{:query=>"salad", :fields=>["name^9", "summary^8", "cuisine_name^7", "description^6"]}}]}}
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Its still not solved ?Can you please share your mapping? I doubt courses is not a nested field. curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/<INDEX_NAME>/_mapping/<INDEX_TYPE>'

Comment: I updated my post  with the mapping json. Thanks again for your help, really appreciate it!

Comment: Thanks. mapping is fine. Did you try it with absolute path of the field. i.e. "courses.course_name" instead of "course_name"?

Comment: Yes, I tried. I updated my post with the query from the search request from RoR. Is it possible to search on multiple nested fields like the query I have ?  If it is, I will know to search for problems somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found what is wrong...In my mapping I am specifying that the name of each nested field is indexed but **"index: :not_analyzed"** . This is needed as these contain multiple words and when I am extracting the names to display in my views (through groovy script), if I don't specify 'not_analyzed' ES will make each word of the name searchable by making an array of the name and the words will be in random order so I can't really reconstruct the name easily... However as the index is not analysed if I search for 'christmas' instead of 'Christmas' ES will find noting as it compares the strings 1:1, this is why my searches couldn't find anything as I was not specifying what I was searching for exactly as it is in the DB.

@rahulroc, thanks for your help!